# Баг с изменением класса в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Идея в том, что есть кнопка, которая при первом нажатии добавляет товар и меняет класс кнопки, а при втором перенаправляет в корзину. Сделано с помощью изменения классов.
Первое нажатие:

```
$(".btn-buy").click(function () {
$(".btn-buy").attr("class", "bought")
$(".bought").text("Оформить заказ")
```

Второе:

```
$(".bought").click( () => {location.header('/cart')})
```

Вроде бы всё работает и класс действительно меняется, но почему то при втором нажатии срабатывает первый код (как-будто бы класс и не менялся), хотя класс кнопки изменился на bought. Это какой-то баг JS или JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз при вызове `$(elem).click(fn)` или `$(elem).on('click', fn)`, функция «привязывается» к элементу и в дальнейшем будет всегда срабатывать при кликах на элемент, если не изменить логику.

Пробуйте в рамках одной функции, через условие:

```
$(".btn-buy").on("click", function () {
  let $btn = $(this); // this - ссылка на кликнутый элемент
  
  if ($btn.hasClass("bought")) {
    location.header('/cart'); // Если класс уже добавлен - перенаправить.
  } else {
    $btn.addClass("bought");
    $btn.text("Оформить заказ");
  }
});
```